# Release file for X is not valid yet error in apt-get update

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-for-windows

When trying to build my ubuntu-based Docker container (Docker for Windows), all of a sudden I get an error similar to

```
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 9h 55min 59s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

and the build fails. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8):

Please try this command.

sudo hwclock --hctosys

I fixed the error by above commands.

Answer (score 1):

It's just about date and time, mine has fixed with this:

```
sudo service ntp restart
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out Docker for Windows has [a problem with clock drift](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4526) (potentially due to laptop sleep).

Solution was to adjust system clock in Docker, e.g.

```
>docker run --privileged -it ubuntu:20.04 
root@0b05be0fc8b6:/# date +%T -s "12:21:43"
```

assuming "12:21:43" is current time in UTC.

Edit: The problem reappeared and looks to be related to Hyper-V and laptop low battery sleep. I upgraded to the latest Windows 10 and switched Docker to use WSL2 instead of the deprecated Hyper-V and the problem is finally gone.